# Find the tables in database being used for asp.net caching?

Tags: asp.net, database, caching, sql-server-2000

I suspect someone would have used database caching somewhere before in some other asp.net project. Further, I suspect a specific database would have been created for the caching needs too. My goal is to re-use what is already there: I need find the connection string to that database and let my asp.net application cache to the same database. Is there anyway I can find tables related to sql server object caching?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET caches in memory not to database by default. It's only user sessions that can be configured to use the database. Any reason for wanting a database implementation of caching (database introduces performance overhead)?

Here's some [info](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/27/extensible-output-caching-with-asp-net-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) on writing an output cache provider in .NET 4.0.

Comment: the application runs in a web farm. The data to be cached are tweets fetched from the twitter web service. Fetching the tweets is an intensive operation, and we feel its better fetching from database rather than web server memory...

Comment: Ah I see - it's not really caching you are looking for then. You want a solution to harvest tweets into your own storage to avoid hitting the web services too often. You can then use output caching when the database tweet data is served in your application. Your question is too generic for something quite specific.